# BackboneJS - how do I encode json with danish characters

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone Collection which has its origin in a json file with some danish characters. How does BackboneJS work with encoding specific languages, in this case Danish?

i read something about json_encode but can't really find examples...

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Danish, Chinese or Russian can all be encoded in UTF and usually are in most scenarios. JSON, being a string, can also be encoded in any UTF flavor... So, in 99.99% of the cases, this isn't a problem you should be concerned about!

Usually, json_encode (I assume you are talking about PHP's json_encode?) or other similar function in other languages are all about transforming a structure in the source language (an array, a hash, a dict, etc.) into its JSON representation, but it has nothing to do with the character encoding of the strings within the JSON representation.

Another way to put it is: if you can transform your JSON file into a Javascript object with $.parseJSON or other utility functions, then you are done with character encoding issues. Backbone isn't involved in this in anyway!